# Is it possible to use different view engines for different views in the *same* ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhaml, viewengine

I'd like to experiment with [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/downloads/list). Can I use the NHaml view engine for a few of my views, without having to convert the entire application (or create a new prototype application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/16/composing-multiple-view-engines.aspx

and

[How to use multiple view engines in ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356843/how-to-use-multiple-view-engines-in-asp-net-mvc-application)