# How do I combine multiple view engines in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use multiple view engines in ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356843/how-to-use-multiple-view-engines-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

I am combining two mvc apps, one using razor and one using web forms view engine.  How do I make the ViewEngine select first one view engine and then the other if a match fails?

Comment: painful duplicate of [How to use multiple view engines in ASP.NET MVC application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356843/how-to-use-multiple-view-engines-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new YourViewEngine())
```

Comment: Thank u . Does it work like routing how the order determines the priority?

Comment: I believe so, but the WebFormsViewEngine is added by default.